# IKVM:Failed to initialize JAXP 1.3 DatatypeFactory class.in IKVM.OpenJDK.XML.Bind error

Tags: java, .net, ikvm, mpxj

I use ikvm with mpxj project.

I have a very simple code like this....

```
 var writer = new MSPDIWriter();
 writer.write(project2, ofilename);
```

I get an exception .net, Failed to initialize JAXP 1.3 DatatypeFactory class.in IKVM.OpenJDK.XML.Bind

> Error:The type initializer for 'net.sf.mpxj.mspdi.MSPDIWriter' threw an exceptio n. Error:Failed to initialize JAXP 1.3 DatatypeFactory
>   class. Error:Provider
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryI mpl
>   not found
>   Error:com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl

I can see this problem seems to be related to IKVM.
Can you tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Are you using the .net assemblies shipped with MPXJ, or have you built your own from the source using IKVMC? Which version of MPXJ (and IKVM is applicable) are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem related to this. Not all ikvm dlls were in the same directory as the executable.

Comment: do you know which one was missing?